# Update PHP variable retrieved from MSSQL SELECT every second

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, odbc

I have been searching around for a solution to this problem for a few days and finally decided to ask you lovely people as there seem to be multiple ways to skin this proverbial cat.

I have a php page (index.php) that currently displays results from a SQL select query using the following external php script (script.php):

```
<?php

{
include('database.php');

// Microsoft SQL Server using the SQL Native Client 11.0 ODBC Driver
$conn = odbc_connect($server,$Username,$Password);

// Query
$qry = $Query; <-- this var is set in the included database.php above

$nextbreach = odbc_exec($conn,$qry);

odbc_close();

}

$nextbreachvalue = odbc_result($nextbreach,"Breached Time");
$nextbreachref = odbc_result($nextbreach,"Reference");

?>
```

`$nextbreachvalue` and `$nextbreachref` are then echo'd in my index.php using

```
<?php echo ($nextbreachref); ?>

<?php echo ($nextbreachvalue); ?>
```

I'm able to do this as i have used {include('script.php');}

---

Whilst this works on loading index.php in the browser I would like to update the variables `$nextbreachref` and `$nextbreachvalue` every second without having to refresh the page.

I have seen many articles suggesting ajax, json and js can achieve this however i'm somewhat confused on how this is achieved in my circumstance especially as many of the online examples use mysql and not mssql.

**Index.php** below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

<?php

{include('script.php');}

?>


</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

            <div id="countdowncontainer">

                    <div id="countdownclock">
                        <p id="ref" ><?php echo ($nextbreachref); ?></p>
                    </div>

            </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Using mssql instead of mysql doesn't affect a solution based on ajax and js, which is the solution for what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic structure for what you are trying to do is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   setInterval(function(){
       $.get("data.php", function( data ) { //receiving the echo from the php data file
          $("#ref").html(data); //putting the echoed value directly into the p tag
       });
   }, 1000); //setting the requests to 1 second each
);
</script>


</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

            <div id="countdowncontainer">

                    <div id="countdownclock">
                        <p id="ref" ></p>
                    </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

And your `data.php` would be similar to the code you have that fecthes data from the database. The difference is that it now echoes the result you want to retrieve in the main page, and does not include any html:

```
<?php

{
include('database.php');

// Microsoft SQL Server using the SQL Native Client 11.0 ODBC Driver
$conn = odbc_connect($server,$Username,$Password);

// Query
$qry = $Query; <-- this var is set in the included database.php above

$nextbreach = odbc_exec($conn,$qry);

odbc_close();

}

$nextbreachvalue = odbc_result($nextbreach,"Breached Time");
$nextbreachref = odbc_result($nextbreach,"Reference");
echo($nextbreachref);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! one additional question now. The php in this example echo's one variable. How can I echo multiple variables (in an array or separately) and then split them up for use within the ajax ? once again thank you for the help thus far :)

Comment: I would suggest json encoding your values, and json parsing in the javascript receiving end, so that you keep an organized structure. You already have functions for both in php and js